# OpenCV C++ Zoom Function

Tags: c++, opencv, zooming

I am using an IP Camera for Human Detection using OpenCV dnn and C++, I need to implement zoom functionality to detect humans from a distance over 10 meters, but I found performing zoom in a live video using c++ doesn't exist (please correct me if I am wrong).

I have tried the following code to zoom my video:

```
cv::Mat src, dst, tmp;
tmp = src;
dst = tmp;
pyrUp(tmp, dst, cv::Size(tmp.cols * 2, tmp.rows * 2));
frame.image = dst;
```

But, Image Pyramids did not zoom my video.

Can you please help me with a zoom function to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 2):

Software zoom it is usually called to the selection of a region of the image (ROI). You must select an appropriate ROI rectangle.

```
int width = 750;
int height = 750;
cv::Rect roi(x, y, width, height);
cv::Mat dst = src(roi);
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, Thanks for the response. Can you please clarify me the following - How Can I select whole screen region using cv::Rect roi(x, y, w, h); .. the reason to ask is post zoom, I need to take pic using OpenCV.

Comment: If you need all the image as a region then there is no need to zoom. If you are asking how to take a pic from an IP camera, there are a lot of tutorials you can find. Please take a look to the OpenCV tutorials.

Comment: I've edited my example to show how to select a 750x750 px ROI. You only have to select where want to _zoom_ in the _src_ image with x and y top left point.

Comment: Hi Carlos, I have done zoom over all the image region in python, but now, I have a much efficient code in c++, that's why I requested you for a whole image zoom. I am already taking pics in OpenCV but a zoomed one gives clarity and covers more distance with out a zoom CCTV camera. Can you please advise me a method to select 750x750 ROI in a screen. –

Comment: Then edit your post to add your python code and rephrase the question. I have no idea of what you want to say with _zoom all the image_.

Comment: @GuruVishnu do you want to resize the window? Did you use matplotlib for displaying images in python?

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I will try your logic and get back to you.

Comment: @zteffi - No. I don't want to resize the window. I want to use zoom on a streaming live video. I will work on the Carlos logic and update you.

Comment: Great! Please, @GuruVishnu mark as resolved if it is finished.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to decimate the image by factor of 2 in each direction, you can call the function this way: 
// specify fx and fy and let the function compute the destination image size.

```
resize(src, dst, Size(), 0.5, 0.5, interpolation);
```